# WP REST API v2 not working with Wordpress 4.9.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have updated to wordpress 4.9.1 and now WP REST API v2 not working!
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Please change the permalink and check. It will not work with the default permalink.